# Dockerfile COPY not overwriting Nginx configuration (or Nginx overwrites on container start) - why?

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have a Dockerfile I use for containerizing Python Flask-based microservices that's based on this base Docker image: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker

In my Dockerfile, I add a custom `nginx.conf` and overwrite Nginx's:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6

ADD nginx.conf nginx.conf

COPY ./app /app
COPY ./data /app/data
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

My custom `nginx.conf` includes only one change - a single `server_name` that I prepare with a custom domain name:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
    server_name my-fully-qualified-domain-name.com;
}
```

The reason for this is that I want to run Let's Encrypt's `certbot` utility to force Nginx to be SSL-only within the container.

**The problem:** Docker refuses to overwrite `nginx.conf`. It pretty much refuses to put anything I try into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`.

Or maybe Docker *does* overwrite it, but something within Nginx on start (at container start) overwrites *my* changes. I haven't figured it out, but I'd really like to clobber that `nginx.conf` with my own changes.

Even attaching to the container and manually overwriting Nginx's configuration - then committing those changes to the container using `docker commit` fails. I suspect there's just something I'm not understanding about how Docker's `COPY` command works or how `docker commit` works - any thoughts/suggestions?

**Note #1** - I have not been able to get a custom `server_name` field working with `certbot` using separate Nginx configuration files (per [these instructions](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker#customizing-nginx-configurations)). The only way I've been able to get `certbot` to pick up the right `server_name` has been by clobbering & overwriting the default `nginx.conf`, hence going this approach. Perhaps I'm simply using custom Nginx configuration files incorrectly - any suggestions on that note would be greatly appreciated - but I had gone down that road before and was not successful.

**Note #2** - I am able to run `certbot` on a *running* container (after attaching & overwriting Nginx's configuration), and that works great - SSL on my container, awesome - until the container stops and restarts. Then it's all wiped away and I need to overwrite Nginx's configuration & run `certbot` again - not ideal at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't overwrite the default `nginx.conf` file (see https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker#customizing-nginx-configurations).

However you can still add your own configuration in a separate file within `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`, which should be enough for most use cases.

**Edit:**

If that doesn't work you can modify `entrypoint.sh` to better suit your needs since `nginx.conf` is set there. This issue contains a bit more info: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker/issues/39

Comment: I have not been able to get a custom `server_name` field working with `certbot` using separate Nginx configuration files (per those instructions). The only way I've been able to get `certbot` to pick up the right `server_name` has been by clobbering & overwriting the default `nginx.conf`, hence going this approach.

Comment: Ok! Have you tried modifying `entrypoint.sh` to better suit your needs? It seems like `nginx.conf` is set there. See this issue for example: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker/issues/39

Comment: Awesome! Hope it works. Edited my answer to provide that info.